# How do I open a pop up box by clicking on jQuery datatable element?

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl, datatables

I want to display a jQuery datatable which contains a column where every element can be clicked and a pop up shows. I produce a datatable and display it using JSP. I display the columns with JSTL as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${catids}" var="current">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${current.targetscode}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.productname}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.role}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.controlint}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.homemoveint}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${current.regradeId}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to hyperlink all the `regradeID`s, so that when a user clicks on a `regradeID` within the datatable, a pop up shows.
Does anyone know how I would do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<c:url>` tag is used to create an url.and u can send the id as a parameter like this,

```
<c:url value="/mypage.jsp" var="completeURL">
 <c:param name="id" value="${current.regradeId}" />

</c:url>
<a href="${completeURL}" />Hyperlink</a>
```